Progressive Morphs / Shape keys in Blender
What's the workflow for Progressive Morphing in Blender - do you have to use Linear morphs. If so how do u combine Relative morphs ?
So at 10% I want one morph that then progresses to another morph at 20% etc
Also what happens if you want Progressive and Relative morphs in one object ?

I’m voting to close this question because the topic is covered directly in the Shape Keys section of the Blender manual.

The manual doesn't show how to combine Progressive Morphs and Relative in one object.

It does show that there is one “Relative” checkbox for the whole mesh, which basically means you can’t do both.
